# SQL - how to get a group with bigger members count

Tags: sql

I have `table1` with `users` divided by two groups in column `gr_type`. I need to output the group with biggest number of users. i've tried smth like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT
       gr_type
       ,RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY gr_type ORDER BY users DESC) as max_users
    FROM table1
)
SELECT
gr_type
,max(max_users)
FROM cte
GROUP BY gr_type
```

so i get output like this and it's outputs both groups with number of users in it.

```
gr_type max_users
gr1     6
gr2     16
```

how can i fix my script for this putput?

```
gr_type max_users
gr2     16
```

Comment: What about ties? Are there other columns that need to come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine you group by and rank() [windown function](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=sql+window+function) in the same query, and then filter the result with rank_num =1

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2c66/2):

```
WITH per_gr_type_max_users AS (
SELECT
    gr_type,
    max(users) as max_users,
    rank() over (order by max(users) desc) as rank_num
FROM table1
group by gr_type
)
select
    gr_type,
    max_users
from
    per_gr_type_max_users
WHERE
    rank_num = 1
```

| gr_type | max_users |
| --- | --- |
| gr2 | 16 |

Comment: Exactly what is needed. using additional 'partition by' confused me) thanks a lot!